# Java-How to save JTable when cells are changed?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in my JPanel and i want to know how to save the edited cells. What happens right now is that when i edit a cell and press ENTER, the new data is shown.But when I close the program and open it again, the data changes back to what is originally was.

Pictures:

While editing the JTable:

[image]

After restarting program:

[image]

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I want to try to get the data from a .txt file inside my project. I'm not really sure how to do that. I dont know how to get the saved data into a .txt file or how to implement it into a JTable.

Comment: What have you tried? You of course need to save it to some file. Memory is not a persistent store.

Comment: I've tried a Table Model Listener. But i don't know what to do with it.

Comment: You should be more explicit about what you want to do with your data to get useful responses. For instance, **Where** do you want to store the changes? From where do you get the data in the first place? What kind of model are you using to store your data on runtime?

Comment: Checkout[TableModel#setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)). You might like to also have a look at [Long Term Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/longpersistence.html) for suggestions about how to persist data between sessions. You might also like to have a look at [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/index.html) as well

Answer (score 2):

The [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) you probably use (as you do not talk about any other) is Serializable. Obtain it using [JTable.getModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29) and write to a file upon shutdown using ObjectOutputStream. On the program startup, load it back using [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInput.html) and set for the table.

If you do not know when your application will terminate, [add the Window closing listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) and save you table model there.

Of course, there are many other ways to save a table between runs.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the TableModelListeners' methods, and trigger a write to disk (in the same format that you use when loading the data) whenever something changes. So, write something like

```
myTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
       // access the values of the model and save them to the file here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Swing is built with MVC in mind. MVC as you probably know stands for Model View Controller.
So Model is somethings that contains data and its decoupled from view which is a graphical representation of the data.

The model is a default table model (or maybe you have another implementation). And the view is  a JTable itself.
Now it works like this:
Controller changes the model. And model sends events to anyone who is interested to know about  such a change.
Controller in this case is also a JTable (the part of it that allows editing).
So in fact after you edit your cell, the table model that stands behind the JTable gets changed (remember, controller knows who is its model so it changes it). 
Now the model says (in swing it sends events) : "I'm changed" - so there is a change event.

The only problem is that no-one probably handles this event so that the model's change will persist through the restart.

I believe what you should do is:
Implement a listener that will take a model and serialize it into file/put into xml file or database - whatever that survives the restart (you can think about the most suitable format).

While I didn't point on specific classes (TableModelListener was already suggested) I thought the overall explanation won't harm here.

Hope, this helps